# Set a default image for thumbnail column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json, image, image-display

Within SharePoint online, I would like to set a custom default image for my "thumbnail" column (or "Hyperlink or Picture"). I named it "Cover Photo".  If I go into my settings for this specific column (displayed below), it invites me to put in JSON code.  Is there where I can pull in a default image from a remote HTTP location? If so, how do I write that here in this JSON box area?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we could use following json to set default value for image column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json" ,

  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
  "width": "100px"
           },
  "attributes": {
  "src": "/sites/Team1/SiteAssets/__siteIcon__.jpg"
      }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Per my test, I use the image stored in current site, you can try to use images from remote HTTP locations.

More information about src attribute:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'll give it a try today.

Comment: That works when the SharePoint view is set to list. But does not work when the view is set to Gallery...regardless, I still like it.